# Javascript not implemented error in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer, radio-button

i used a javascript code for radiobtn check inside gridview. the code works fine in firefox browser. but in internet explorer (IE) the code is not working and the error says Javascript not implemented. my javascript code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function CheckOtherIsCheckedByGVID(rb) {

        var isChecked = rb.checked;
        var row = rb.parentNode.parentNode;
        if (isChecked) {
            row.style.backgroundColor = '#C4DFFB';
            row.style.color = 'black';
        }
        var currentRdbID = rb.id;
        parent = document.getElementById("<%= grdEventDetails.ClientID %>");
        var items = parent.getElementsByTagName('input');

        for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            if (items[i].id != currentRdbID && items[i].type == "radio") {
                if (items[i].checked) {
                    items[i].checked = false;
                    items[i].parentNode.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
                    items[i].parentNode.parentNode.style.color = '#696969';
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

my implementation in gridview code is

```
   <asp:TemplateField>
     <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
    <ItemTemplate>
   <asp:RadioButton ID="grdRdo" runat="server"
 onclick="javascript:CheckOtherIsCheckedByGVID(this);" />
  </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: It's good to do this just after the script tag: `//<![CDATA[` and before the end tag of script: `//]]>`. Does that solve the problem? IE can have difficulties if you don't put it there... Oh and a handy way to "debug" javascript code is to put alert statements to alert variables content. If you see the messageboxes popup and the value is correct, the error occurs further in your function. Put multiple alerts (like alert(item[i]) in the for loop and one in the if-statement) to see where it goes wrong.

Comment: which version of IE you are using

Comment: ie 8 . i used alert box before document.getelementId(); after dat it shows d same not implemented error

Comment: yes i was facing sometime back the same problem and it was only in IE.please give any solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try renaming the parent variable. It sounds like something that would conflict with the pre-existing environment.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "onclick" event on your Page_Load function:

```
grdRdo.Attributes.Add("onclick", "CheckOtherIsCheckedByGVID(this)");
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
parent = document.getElementById("<%= grdEventDetails.ClientID %>");
```

to:

```
var parent = document.getElementById("<%= grdEventDetails.ClientID %>");
```

IE seems to like the 'var' in there when you are declaring variables.